# Compare value in ng-repeat with php value

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am trying to fill an array in javascript with data fetched from database in PHP. I am running into issues as the array isn't being looped through and seems to be empty after running the query.

Here is my code:

PHP

```
public function getAllFavorites() {
        $json = array();
        $query = $this -> db -> get("favorites");
        $count = $query -> num_rows();
        foreach ($query -> result() as $row) {
            array_push($json, $row -> product_id);
        }
        echo json_encode($json);
    }
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
app.controller("MainController", function($scope, $http){
    $scope.favorites = getAllFavorites();
});
var getAllFavorites = function() {
    $.get("/home/getAllFavoriteIds", function(response){
        return response;
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="favorite in favorites">{{favorite}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

All I am trying to do is fill $scope.favorites with the array returned from my PHP, and then loop through using ng-repeat.

Comment: You need to be using `$http` or the data bindings will break.  More specifically something like `$http.get("/home/getAllFavoriteIds")` and in the success callback you would set `$scope.favorites = response.data`

Comment: Can't return from an ajax callback in the first place. Your outer function `getAllFavorites` returns nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with your JS. Your code expects a synchronous return of data from `getAllFavorites()`, but that function doesn't return anything. Use $http to make your call and it'll give you a promise back. You can use that promise to respond when the client gets the data.

```
app.controller("MainController", function($scope, $http){
    var getAllFavorites = function() {
        return $http.get("/home/getAllFavoriteIds"); // This should really be done in a service
    };

    getAllFavorites().then(function(response){
        $scope.favorites = response.data;
    });
});
```